# Why am I getting tis OCI runtime error even though deployment is created

Tags: kubernetes

My Yaml file looks like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - name: mongodbport
          containerPort: 27017
          protocol: TCP
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
```

My secret yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: mongodb-secret
type: opaque
data:
    mongo-root-username: JwB2AG8AbABoAGEAcgBkACcA
    mongo-root-password: JwBEAGgAYQBuAHUAcwBoACcA
```

Error image:
[Description of error could be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZzyW.png)

There is also a reference for DB credentials if you observe ,if that's needed to debug then I would love to provide. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please provide details of error you're getting

Comment: provided link to error image if you wanna see

Comment: It's your whole deployment? You are not using any volumes?

Comment: No volumes yet mate just a simple  deployment with a Secret

Comment: Usually `kubectl` commands will write out text diagnostics, not an image.  Please replace that link with the actual output of the command and not a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your secret. Are you trying to store binary value or null byte in your secret?

Please take a look: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/89906

Comment: could you please help me if I share secret yaml file please

Comment: try to remove quotes from your secret values

Comment: There are no quotation marks for key value pairs I think

Comment: your secret values are base64 encoded. You need to decode them, remove the quotes and then recreate the secret. Please read the Kubernetes docs on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are **2 issues** with your current configuration. I've tested on my `Minikube` cluster.

**Issue 1** is related with your `secret`.

When you will decode your `secret` you will find out that values of`mongo-root-username` and `mongo-root-password` have `'`. You can verify it using command

```
$ echo JwB2AG8AbABoAGEAcgBkACcA | base64 --decode
'vo...rd'
$ echo JwBEAGgAYQBuAHUAcwBoACcA | base64 --decode
'Dh..sh`
```

In [Kubernetes Secret Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret) under one of the `Use cases` you can find *Note* information about `'`.

> **Note:**
> Special characters such as $, , *, =, and ! will be interpreted by your shell and require escaping. In most shells, the easiest way to escape the password is to surround it with single quotes ('). For example, if your actual password is S!B*d$zDsb=, you should execute the command this way:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic dev-db-secret --from-literal=username=devuser --from-literal=password='S!B\*d$zDsb='
```

but if you will encode it, you will see that password do not contains `'` characters.

```
$ kubectl get secrets/dev-db-secret --template={{.data.password}} | base64 --decode
S!B\*d$zDsb=
```

**Issue 2** is related with lack of any `Volume` where your `Mongodb` could save data.

```
$ kubectl logs mongodb-deployment-79d5b75846-jk9ss
...
Error saving history file: FileOpenFailed Unable to open() file /home/mongodb/.dbshell: No such file or directory
```

You have to provide some `Volumes` otherwise your pod will get error.

#### Solution

Change secrets `mongo-root-username` and `mongo-root-password`to values without `'`. You can do it using command:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic dev-db-secret --from-literal=username=devuser --from-literal=password=YourPassword
```

or manually with proper encoding:

```
$ echo devuser | base64
ZGV2dXNlcgo=
$ echo YourPassword | base64
WW91clBhc3N3b3JkCg==
```

While you are using `Database` images like `MySQL` or `MongoDB` you have to specify [Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) to allow your database some read/write operations. Otherwise your container will stuck in `CrashLoopBackOff` loop.

Below my YAMLs which was tested on `Minikube 1.16` and secret contains your values without `'`.

`secret.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: mongodb-secret
type: opaque
data:
    mongo-root-username: dm9saGFyZAo=
    mongo-root-password: RGhhbnVzaAo=
```

`pvpvc.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/mongopv/
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mongo-claim
  name: mongo-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: manual
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

`deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo
        name: mongodb
        ports:
        - name: mongodbport
          containerPort: 27017
          protocol: TCP
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/db
          name: mongo-claim
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-claim
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-claim
```

Just as additional information, you you would use more replicas you will need to provide new `pv` and `pvc`. It's good practice to use `Statefulset` with [VolumeClaimTemplate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-storage) for that.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue please accept it.